# tf.image.crop_and_resize() return 0 values when assigned to GPU on the Jetson TX2

Tags: python, tensorflow

#### System information

- **Have I written custom code (as opposed to using a stock example script provided in TensorFlow)**: Yes
- **OS Platform and Distribution (e.g., Linux Ubuntu 16.04)**: 16.04.LTS
- **TensorFlow installed from (source or binary)**: Source
- **TensorFlow version (use command below)**: 1.3.0
- **Python version**:  2.7.12
- **Bazel version (if compiling from source)**: 0.5.2
- **CUDA/cuDNN version**: 8.0/6.0.21
- **GPU model and memory**: Nvidia Tegra X2
- **Exact command to reproduce**:`tf.image.crop_and_resize(raw_sample, boxes, box_ind)`

#### Describe the problem

I'm getting completly different results from tensorflow's function `tf.image.crop_and_resize(...)` when assigned it to gpu and cpu.
In other words:

- when I run this ops on CPU, I get correct results( I mean, the  right crops)
- when I put it on the GPU device I get crops fulled with 0 values.

#### Source code / logs

Here, you can see a simple use case:

```
import tensorflow as tf 
import numpy as np
import cv2 #Just importing cv2 to read  image, you use PIL or anything else to load it

device='gpu' 

def img2batch_crops(input_image):
    raw_sample_tensor_4d=tf.expand_dims(input_image, 0)

    #Setting the size to crop and the final size of cropped images
    patches_top=[0,0.5]
    patches_bottom =[0.5,0.5]
    crop_size = [100,100]
    boxes=tf.stack([patches_top, patches_top, patches_bottom, patches_bottom], axis=1)

    ##Here is the bug:
        #When device == 'cpu', I got  results 
        #When device == 'gpu', I got  black cropped images( 0 values)
    with tf.device('/'+device+':0'):  
        crops=tf.image.crop_and_resize(raw_sample_tensor_4d, boxes, box_ind=tf.zeros_like(patches_top, dtype=tf.int32), crop_size=crop_size, name="croper")

    return crops


def main():

    img_data = cv2.imread('image.jpg') #Just loading the image,

    print("Shape and type of image input ",img_data.shape, img_data.dtype) #Print the shape and the type of the image, supposed to be a numpy array

    raw_image = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=img_data.shape, name='input_image')

       crops = img2batch_crops(raw_image) # Adding ops to the graph

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        myBatchedImages = sess.run(crops, feed_dict={raw_image:img_data})
        cv2.imwrite('result_'+device+'.jpg',myBatchedImages[0])   ## Savej just one cropped image to see how it looks like

main()
```

Comment: Could you include the image you are testing on, just for the sake of completeness

Comment: You can use any kind *.jpg, it gives the same results

Comment: did you try with different precisions (8, 16, 32, 64 bit)? maybe precision gets downcasted somewhere?

Comment: I just tried your code on my own computer, using this image: https://www.tensorflow.org/images/daisies.jpg, and got the same correct results on both CPU and GPU. Could you share your image, and cropped results?

Comment: @denfromufa, yes I tried, but get the same results

Comment: @Mingxing, the code give good results on my computer too, but the problem is with the Jetson TX2